# Calculation of spherical Bessel functions - meaning of $\left(\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{l}$

Tags: mathematical-physics, mathematics, special-functions

I'm trying to understand the calculation of [spherical Bessel functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Spherical_Bessel_functions%3a_jn.2C_yn) in chapter four of Griffiths' Introduction to Quantum Mechanics (2nd ed, p142). He gives $$j_{2}\left(x\right)=\left(-x\right)^{2}\left(\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{2}\frac{\sin x}{x}=x^{2}\left(\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx}\right)\frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^{3}}$$

$$=\frac{3\sin x-3x\cos x-x^{2}\sin x}{x^{3}}.$$

I can't see how he arrives at this answer. I think my problem is the $\left(\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{2}$
  bit (the general term for $j_{l}\left(x\right)$
  is $\left(\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx}\right)^{l}$
 ). I'm assuming this means $1/x^{2}$
  multiplied by the second derivative of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$
  but I make that $$\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)\left(-\frac{\sin x}{x}+\frac{2\sin x}{x^{3}}-\frac{2\cos x}{x^{2}}\right).$$

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The term $\left(\frac1x \frac d{dx}\right)^2$ should be understood to mean the operator
$$\left(\frac1x \frac d{dx}\right)^2=\frac1x \frac d{dx}\frac1x \frac d{dx}.$$
Otherwise one would simply say $\frac1{x^2} \frac {d^2}{dx^2}$. Check the derivation of the formula you use for the spherical Bessel functions to get a feel for why this must be the case.

Comment: Thanks. So, in this case, you'd simply take the derivative, then multiply by 1/x, then take the derivative again and then multiply by 1/x? Afraid I'm not too familiar with operators.

Comment: Yes Peter, thats what you do. $\frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{x} \frac{d}{dx} \phi= \frac{1}{x}\frac{d}{dx}  \frac{1}{x} \phi^\prime $. Mind that you need to apply  of the product rule for derivations when you use the second $\frac{d}{dx}$ term